# TypeError: klik() missing 1 required positional argument: 'j'

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

I have an issue with creating function. When i run it it always show TypeError: klik() missing 1 required positional argument: 'j' and i don't know how to fix it.

```
def klik(h,j):
    global w,z
    for h in range(0,100):
        for j in range(0,100):
            if m[h][j]==0.0:
                f='white'
            else:
                f='black'
        canvas.create_rectangle(w,z,w+strana,z+strana, fill=f, outline="" )
        w+=strana
    z+=strana
    w=0
canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', klik)
```

Comment: try with : def klik(h):

Comment: it don't works bcs it only render first row and i need to render all 100 rows in one click